# Assign custom class permissions check for controller actions in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, reflection, permissions

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 site with custom user/role provider. Entity Framework works with the user and role entities at the bottom level. Now I am introducing a concept of `RolePermission`s. Each role has an asscocialted list of permissions that allow users in this role to perform certain actions within the system, like deleting comments for example.

In my custom-build admin panel I want to list all the actions of a controllers and have an ability to allow or disallow the call to some action based on the presenace of a permission in the curent user's role.

Questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. How do I list a set of actions in the controller.
3. How do I assign or cancel an association between action and a role permission.

Possible starategy:

I introduce a global custom filter that is applied to all of the controllers and actions, that checks my database to see If I have a logical association. This way a checking code is ran every time the user makes a call to an action. Still how do I list controllers and actions (via reflection perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Still how do I list controllers and actions (via reflection perhaps?)

Yes, reflection is one way to do it. Here's an example of how to get a list of all controller types:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> GetControllers()
{
    IEnumerable<Type> typesSoFar = Type.EmptyTypes;
    var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies();
    foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
    {
        Type[] typesInAsm;
        try
        {
            typesInAsm = assembly.GetTypes();
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
        {
            typesInAsm = ex.Types;
        }
        typesSoFar = typesSoFar.Concat(typesInAsm);
    }
    return typesSoFar.Where(type => 
        type != null && 
        type.IsPublic && 
        type.IsClass && 
        !type.IsAbstract && 
        typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    );
}
```

and then you could get a list of `ActionDescriptor` for each controller type:

```
foreach (var controller in GetControllers())
{
    ActionDescriptor[] actions = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controller).GetCanonicalActions();
    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
        // here you know everything about the action
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the list of actions is always empty becuase `controller.GetType() returns a RuntimeType that, when reflected as ControllerDescriptor has no actions. But the controller.Name is correct name of my web site controllers.

Comment: Ok, found a problem - `ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controller).GetCanonicalActions();` There was no need to call controller.GetType() since controller variable already hold a type object.